# C# .net First ImageButton in loop cannot be modified

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

My problem seem simple but I can't find the answer.

So I'm creating a loop to read into a textile and create some dynamic buttons, everything's seem to work but the first buttons can't be modified right after his initialization.

If someone has already encountered this issue...

Thank you for your help

My code :

```
<%
    string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path + "/text/BdD.txt");

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        { 
%>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <%
        }
        string[] wo = lines[i++].Split(';');
        string screen = wo[4].Substring(2);
        %>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

            <a class="thumbnail" style="height:250px;" name="
<%Response.Write(i);%>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="
<%Response.Write(wo[2]); %>"!">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1 style="font-size:20px;"><%Response.Write(wo[1]);%></h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <%
        ImageButton1.AlternateText = "";
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = screen;
        ImageButton1.CssClass = wo[0] + " img_button_menu";
        ImageButton1.Click += (s, ev) =>
        {
            var id_bdd = ImageButton1.CssClass;
            id_bdd = id_bdd.Substring(0, 36);
            foreach (string line_app in lines)
            {
                string[] app_path = lines[j++].Split(';');
                if (app_path[0] == id_bdd)
                {
                    LaunchProcess(app_path);
                }
            }
        };
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        { 
        %>
    </div>
</div>
<%
        }
    }
%>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
```

HTML output :

> 

```
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

            <a class="thumbnail" style="height:250px;" name="1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="TEST"!">
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton1" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1 style="font-size:20px;">TEST</h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

            <a class="thumbnail" style="height:250px;" name="2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="TEST"!">
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton1" class="85a317b8-872e-4221-8a9b-b1d57702177a img_button_menu" src="img/85a317b8-872e-4221-8a9b-b1d57702177a.jpg" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1 style="font-size:20px;">TEST</h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">

            <a class="thumbnail" style="height:250px;" name="3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="TEST"!">
                <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton1" class="87e0ca66-e663-4a36-9fb2-00b0b3252831 img_button_menu" src="img/87e0ca66-e663-4a36-9fb2-00b0b3252831.jpg" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h1 style="font-size:20px;">TEST</h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: probably cos you called them all "ImageButton1" - try giving them a unique name

Comment: I dont think so, every iteration work except the first one

Comment: Then please explain more of the modifications you are trying to do and how they arent working

Comment: I'm trying to modify the URLImage, the class, and the alternate text but no one are applied, to illustrate: http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=510399test.png

Comment: Can you provide the HTML output?

Comment: @C1rdec I just updated my question with HTML output